# How can I get lift value of association rules using Spark FP-growth in Pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

```
fpGrowth = FPGrowth(itemsCol="items", minSupport=0.5, minConfidence=0.6)
model = fpGrowth.fit(df)
model.associationRules.show()
```

Using the above code, I can only get the confidence of each association rule. But how can I get **'lift'** value of each association rule using Spark FP-growth in Pyspark?

in the case, I only have these two dataframes, how can I add the lift value behind the confidence value in the first dataframe **automatically(not adding manually**?

```
+----------+----------+------------------+
|antecedent|consequent|        confidence|
+----------+----------+------------------+
|    [2, 1]|       [5]|0.6666666666666666|
|    [5, 1]|       [2]|               1.0|
|       [2]|       [1]|               1.0|
|       [2]|       [5]|0.6666666666666666|
|       [5]|       [2]|               1.0|
|       [5]|       [1]|               1.0|
|    [5, 2]|       [1]|               1.0|
|       [1]|       [2]|               1.0|
|       [1]|       [5]|0.6666666666666666|
+----------+----------+------------------+

+---------+----+------------------+
|    items|freq|           support|
+---------+----+------------------+
|      [1]|   3|               1.0|
|      [2]|   3|               1.0|
|   [2, 1]|   3|               1.0|
|      [5]|   2|0.6666666666666666|
|   [5, 2]|   2|0.6666666666666666|
|[5, 2, 1]|   2|0.6666666666666666|
|   [5, 1]|   2|0.6666666666666666|
+---------+----+------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to calculate: Lift is the confidence `C` quotient. So the lift for a rule is the confidence `C(a->b)/C(b)`. For example if the confidence of `bread -> cheese` is `1.2` and the confidence of `-> cheese` is `1.1`, then the lift is  `1.2/1.1`.

See [here](http://www.borgelt.net/doc/fpgrowth/fpgrowth.html#lift)

Comment: Thank, but how can I use `[2, 1] -> [5]   confidence: 0.6666666666666666` to get the support of [5], then using this confidence/support to get the lift, namely how can I get the confidence of [5], in the case I only have the confidence of each rule.  Is there a variable of Spark to store support value of each frequent item?

Comment: 0.66 means that in 2/3rd of the cases of 2,1, the set also contains 5. So the support of 5 is the fraction of 5 in the all sets.

Comment: I have changed my question, could you please answer the new question?

Answer (score -2):

```
df1.join(df2,df2.items==df1.consequent, 'left').select("antecedent","consequent","confidence","support").show()

+----------+----------+------------------+------------------+
|antecedent|consequent|        confidence|           support|
+----------+----------+------------------+------------------+
|    [2, 1]|       [5]|0.6666666666666666|0.6666666666666666|
|       [2]|       [5]|0.6666666666666666|0.6666666666666666|
|       [1]|       [5]|0.6666666666666666|0.6666666666666666|
|       [2]|       [1]|               1.0|               1.0|
|       [5]|       [1]|               1.0|               1.0|
|    [5, 2]|       [1]|               1.0|               1.0|
|    [5, 1]|       [2]|               1.0|               1.0|
|       [5]|       [2]|               1.0|               1.0|
|       [1]|       [2]|               1.0|               1.0|
+----------+----------+------------------+------------------+
```